# detect service in another host on docker swarm

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

There are three linux pc, such as A (with ubutun 16.04), B (centos 7), C (centos 7). And I have installed docker 18.03.1-ce on them. I inited a swarm, and nodes list below:
[image]

Now, I used a docker-compose.yml as follow:
[image]

Accoroding to this yml, and a swarm network named 'ishop_default' was created on each node, and services can detect each other in the
same host, but failed to detect services in other hosts.

Answer (score 0):

As docker-compose.yaml you attached, there is no network configuration. Specify your own network in the docker-compose.yaml file like below.

```
versin: "3.1"
services:
  redis:
    imgae: redis:latest
    networks:
      - ishop_default
...
networks:
  ishop_default:
    external: true
```

Refer to docker's guide - https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/#specify-custom-networks

Comment: Thanks for your help. I noticed this config, but didn't know how to configure the external network.